# Rudin's RCA Theorem $3.5$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

There is the definition which we need for the theorem:

[image]

There is the theorem:

Let $p$ and $q$ be conjugate exponents, $1 \lt p \lt \infty$. Let $X$ be a measure space, with measure $\mu$. Let $f$ and $g$ be measurable functions on $X$, with range in $[0,\infty]$. Then

$$\int_X fg d\mu \leq \left( \int_X f^{p} d\mu \right)^{1/p}\left(\int_X g^{q} d\mu\right)^{1/q}$$

There is the proof:

Let $A$ and $B$ be the two factors on the right of the inequality. If $A = 0$, then $f = 0 a.e$; hence fg $= 0 a.e.$, so the inequality holds. If $A \gt 0$ and $B = \infty$, the inequality is trivial.
so we need consider only the case $0 \lt A \lt \infty$,$\lt B \lt \infty$.
Put

$F = \frac {f}{A} $,  $G = \frac {g}{B} $.

This gives

$\int_X F^p d\mu = \int_X G^q d\mu  = 1$

I don't understand why are $\int_X F^p d\mu$ and $\int_X G^q d\mu$ equal of $1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use  ```\{``` instead of leaving math mode: ```$\leq$ { $\int_X f^{p} $```

Comment: I guess $A=\left(\int f^p\right)^{1/p}$ and $B=\left(\int g^q\right)^{1/q}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as Holder's Inequality. It is common to first show that it suffices to show Holder's Inequality holds for functions $f,g$ with norm 1. One then uses Young's inequality: $$ab \leq \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$$, which holds for $a,b\geq 0$ and $p,q$ Holder conjuagtes.

To answer your question,
$$\int_X F^p\,d\mu = A^{-p}\int_X f^p\,d\mu = 1 $$